# Failed to instantiate one or more classes?

Tags: java, android, android-youtube-api

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;
    youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.view);
    onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("Z2xmB1QgR5U");
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };
    youTubePlayerView.initialize("key of youtube ",onInitializedListener);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;
    youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.view);
    onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("Z2xmB1QgR5U");
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };
    youTubePlayerView.initialize("AIzaSyDikzotm49vUXmyorjsoMXs9R-vh_yfUo4",onInitializedListener);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

content_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.bucky.youtubetest.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    class="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView"
    id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-6dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="126dp" />
```

[image]

I have added youtubeplayer view in my app and I got this error... when I run my app it crashes in my phone.. Can any one plaese help me it mean a lot for me...

logcat

```
 Process: com.example.bucky.youtubetest, PID: 19639
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bucky.youtubetest/com.example.bucky.youtubetest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3190)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                               at com.example.bucky.youtubetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                               at com.example.bucky.youtubetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
                                                                               at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                               at com.example.bucky.youtubetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the Youtube library dependency. But it's hard to tell without any logs...

Comment: I have added Youtube library... and you can check logcat I have added

Comment: You can also check the logcat you added. The solution is right there. `YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity`

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can
>   only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as
>   its context.

So try to change your `Activity` declaration to following:

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity 
     implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
```